# Drag the inner html of an element and drop it in another element while mouse is down

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events

I have a grid where I have a `start node.` How can I make this a **draggable** object. I don't want to move the HTML element itself because it contains information about that node (position, state, etc). I just want to move the `inner html` of it to another HTML element, this is so that HTML element information such as `x` and `y` coordinates don't move.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

> How can I achieve that effect?

I have the following function for event handling:

```
const events = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
      const node = board[i][j];
      node.DOMElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
          // Click events ocurr here for a Node in a specific x and y position in the board
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think the concept of "drag this whole html thing" is anything available natively, the closest is to have functionality to cut out the contents and paste into new box in a `mouse enter` event, I feel like this question is pretty broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I've comed up with a workaround for my specific problem. I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following did the trick! Just added/removed the stuff that I need when mouse enters or leaves the tile.

```
let mouseDown: boolean = false;
let startNodeSelected: boolean = false;
let targetNodeSelected: boolean = false;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  mouseDown = true;
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  mouseDown = false;
});

export const events = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
      const node: Node = board[i][j];
      const nodeElement: HTMLElement = board[i][j].DOMElement;

      nodeElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        removeStartNodeOnDrag(node, nodeElement);
      });

      nodeElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        addStartNodeOnDrag(node, nodeElement);
      });

      nodeElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        removeTargetNodeOnDrag(node, nodeElement);
      });

      nodeElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        addTargetNodeOnDrag(node, nodeElement);
      });
    }
  }
};

const removeStartNodeOnDrag = (node: Node, nodeElement: HTMLElement) => {
  if (node.type === "start" && mouseDown) {
    nodeElement.classList.remove("start");
    node.type = "empty";
    node.state = "unvisited";
    startNodeSelected = true;
  }
};

const addStartNodeOnDrag = (node: Node, nodeElement: HTMLElement) => {
  if (node.type === "empty" && mouseDown && startNodeSelected) {
    nodeElement.classList.add("start");
    node.type = "start";
    node.state = "visited";
    startNodeSelected = false;
  }
};

const removeTargetNodeOnDrag = (node: Node, nodeElement: HTMLElement) => {
  if (node.type === "target" && mouseDown) {
    nodeElement.classList.remove("target");
    node.type = "empty";
    targetNodeSelected = true;
  }
};

const addTargetNodeOnDrag = (node: Node, nodeElement: HTMLElement) => {
  if (node.type === "empty" && mouseDown && targetNodeSelected) {
    nodeElement.classList.add("target");
    node.type = "target";
    targetNodeSelected = false;
  }
};
```